# select only non space and word characters in ruby from a string

Tags: ruby, string

Im coding my fist program in ruby.
I want to select all characters from a string except of whitespace and nonword characters to compare to my other string.
I know i can select nonwhite space characters by using `\S` on my string and I can select word only characters by calling `\w` on my string but i cant find anywhere how to combine those two to select only nonwhitespace word characters only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Word characters are all nonwhitespace characters, so `\w` will suffice.

Answer (score 0):

This online Ruby regex simulator can also be of help if you have a block of text to try.

http://rubular.com/

Also Ruby does support $1 $2 $3, etc like Perl and other languages.